# how to use a controller variable in my layout

Tags: layout, controller, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to use a variable of my controller in my layout.

For example:
`@posts = Post.all.count`

In my layout I want to list the Post count, even when I open the index view of another controller.

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions:

- Use `<%= Post.all.count %>` in your layout.
- Add a `before_filter` in your `ApplicationController` that loads the variable.

  ```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :load_layout_variables

  protected
    def load_layout_variables
      @posts = Post.all.count
    end
  end
  ```